# Scribe jobs not getting complete

Tags: dynamics-crm, integration, sage-erp, scribe-workbench

I am working on `Sage ERP MAS 200` and `Microsoft Dynamics CRM` integration using `Scribe`.

When I trying to run a Scribe job, it is not getting completed. What is happening is: out of 3583 source rows, it processes 3580 rows and then the application freezes. When I click on the option named 'View problem details', I end up getting following error message:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
Application Name:                             TWorkbench.exe
Application Version:                           7.7.0.43481
Application Timestamp:                     52f94524
Fault Module Name:                          StackHash_cbad
Fault Module Version:                        6.1.7601.18247
Fault Module Timestamp:                  521ea8e7
Exception Code:                                  c0000374
Exception Offset:                                000ce753
OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
Locale ID:                                             1033
Additional Information 1:                  cbad
Additional Information 2:                  cbad5e25586823adf3bcd0ccb9c3d855
Additional Information 3:                  971b
Additional Information 4:                  971b988a031cb700377a15a97d1b79e6

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I modified my query using the `Configure Source` option and divided the original query into subqueries. After that most of the subqueries are running fine, except couple of them (which do not get complete and give the same error as above).

Can anybody please help me with this?